# Python Quickselect not printing/returning pivot

Tags: python, median, quickselect

Here is the code for quickselect

```
def quickSelect(lst, k):
if len(lst) != 0:
    pivot = lst[(len(lst)) // 2]
    smallerList = []
    for i in lst:
        if i < pivot:
            smallerList.append(i)
    largerList = []
    for i in lst:
        if i > pivot:
            largerList.append(i)
    count = len(lst) - len(smallerList) - len(largerList)
    m = len(smallerList)
    if k >= m and k < m + count:
        return pivot
        print(pivot)
    elif m > k:
        return quickSelect(smallerList, k)
    else:
        return quickSelect(largerList, k-m-count)
```

the issue I am having with it is that it runs with no errors or anything, but when it completes itself I am expecting it to output something to the python shell (in this specific case a median of a list), but I get nothing back. Am I doing something wrong here?

As for what I am inputting for lst and k....

- lst = [70, 120, 170, 200]
- k = len(lst) // 2

I have tried it with a few different k values as well but to no avail

Comment: Might be just poor formatting, but your indentation is wrong. You're not indenting after the function definition.

Comment: I just ran it (fixing the indenting) and with your input for lst and k and quickSelect(lst, k) returned 170.  Could you say how you're calling quickSelect and what your expecting?  Try print(quickSelect(lst, k))) to be sure the interpreter prints the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def quickSelect(lst, k):
    if len(lst) != 0:
        pivot = lst[(len(lst)) // 2]
        smallerList = []
        for i in lst:
            if i < pivot:
                smallerList.append(i)
        largerList = []
        for i in lst:
            if i > pivot:
                largerList.append(i)
        count = len(lst) - len(smallerList) - len(largerList)
        m = len(smallerList)
        if k >= m and k < m + count:
            return pivot
            print(pivot)
        elif m > k:
            return quickSelect(smallerList, k)
        else:
            return quickSelect(largerList, k-m-count)

lst = [70, 120, 170, 200]
k = len(lst) // 2

print(quickSelect(lst, k))
```

produces

```
>>> 170
```

The only thing I corrected was the indenting.

Comment: the "print(quickSelect(lst, k))" was my issue. I was calling for print within the function. When I ran it like this it worked. Formatting was actually correct I just copy+pasted it weird into here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize this algorithm using list comprehension. Also, I don't think you need count...

```
 def quickSelect(seq, k):
    # this part is the same as quick sort
    len_seq = len(seq)
    if len_seq < 2: return seq

    ipivot = len_seq // 2
    pivot = seq[ipivot]

    smallerList = [x for i,x in enumerate(seq) if x <= pivot and  i != ipivot]
    largerList = [x for i,x in enumerate(seq) if x > pivot and  i != ipivot]

    # here starts the different part
    m = len(smallerList)
    if k == m:
        return pivot
    elif k < m:
        return quickSelect(smallerList, k)
    else:
        return quickSelect(largerList, k-m-1)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Checking the Answer
    seq = [10, 60, 100, 50, 60, 75, 31, 50, 30, 20, 120, 170, 200]

    # we want the middle element
    k = len(seq) // 2

    # Note that this only work for odd arrays, since median in
    # even arrays is the mean of the two middle elements
    print(quickSelect(seq, k))
    import numpy
    print numpy.median(seq)
```

Comment: Your code is excellent, but it would be even simpler if `pivot` was simply defined as `seq[0]`; that way you would not need to use `enumerate` at all: `smallerList = [x for x in in seq[1:] if x <= pivot]` and `largerList = [x for x in seq[1:] if x > pivot]`.

Comment: We could this, however we need to be careful with the pivot's choice. For instance, if we end up always parting into n-1 subarrays, quicksort will have a runtime O(n^2) instead of O(nlogn). Choosing the pivot in the middle doesn't prevent this to happen, but it makes it less likely than choosing the pivot in the beginning.